# fill out secretword with guessedword in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am working on a word guessing game.
there are secret words and guessed words for this game. The secret word should be hidden from the user, for example, if the secret word is "Hello" then the result will be ".....".

My question is that if I guess a correct letter for the secret word and I want to put this correctly guessed letter in its actual place in the original word, for example, if the secret word is "Hello" and someone types "e", The result should look like (. e . . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **String.Insert(Int32, String)** method to update your secret string.

You learn about it more from its documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=net-6.0

Also, here is a quick example of its usage

```
class Program
{
    private static string _actualWord = "HELLO";
    private static string _secret = ".....";
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"The Secret Word is: {_secret}");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease guess a letter");
        
        string guess = Console.ReadLine();

        if (_actualWord.Contains(guess))
        {
            int index = _actualWord.IndexOf(guess);
            _secret = _secret.Insert(index, guess);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {_secret}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nIncorrect Guess");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Also - no need to propose edits to questions which are off-topic as written (and please don't propose generic tags like `string` - this one really isn't relevant to the question).